# Sharing a variable within a package in go

Tags: go

I am writing a Go app that will need to connect to a MongoDB for persistence.

I want the client connection to be shared (so that I do not have to re-initialize/create the client connection for each operation). (the program will expose a restful API so each operation will more or less correspond to an HTTP request).

So (since this is still a draft project and still a single file application) I though going about it like this.

a) declare a package scoped pointer var for the client connection

```golang
var mongoClient *mongo.Client
```

b) initialize it in main

```golang
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")
mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
```

and then

c) use it in a handler function e.g.

```golang
collection := mongoClient.Database("mydb").Collection("mycollection")
```

The problem is that the program does not compile with the error:

> mongoClient declared and not used

My workaround was to either

**A**. add the following line within `main()` after the variables initialization

```golang
    mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    _ = mongoClient
```

OR

**B**. use throwaway variable for the error so that I have only var initialization (and not declaration as follows

```golang
mongoClient, _ = mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
```

but that prevents me from the error handling.

Is any other (better) practice / established pattern for this problem?
Is this the right practice?

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
```

Remember that `:=` **declares and initializes a *new* variable**. So you're creating a *new*, *local* variable named `mongoClient` here, which shadows the global; the global remains unchanged. Change this instead to:

```
var err error
mongoClient, err = mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
```